# mmacell shows a quotation mark instead of Input[1]:

Tags: packages, wolfram-mathematica

Please help me with the following question. I would like to add Mathematica code to my latex file. I tried with the package \usepackage{mmacells} and followed the instruction as in the answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73223/how-best-to-embed-various-cell-groups-into-a-latex-project). Here is an example of the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=20mm, paperwidth=100mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mmacells}
\begin{document}

\begin{mmaCell}{Input}
\mmaSub{x}{1} == \mmaFrac{-\mmaUnd{\(\pmb{\beta}\)} \(\pmb{\pm}\) \mmaSqrt{\mmaSup{\mmaUnd{\(\pmb{\beta}\)}}{2} - 4 \mmaUnd{\(\pmb{\alpha}\)} \mmaUnd{\(\pmb{\gamma}\)}}}{2 \mmaUnd{\(\pmb{\alpha}\)}}
\end{mmaCell}

\end{document}
```

Here is what I received after running the above code.

[image]

There is a weird quotation mark above the letter x which is not what I want. It should look like this:
Input[1]: x_1 =...

Hope my question is clear enough.

Edit: I resolved my question by adding \mmaSet{uselistings=false}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.